# Stop div from following scroll before it reaches the footer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been using the following script to make a div on my page float down as the page scrolls.

This is the script:

```
(function($) {
    var element = $('.follow-scroll'),
        originalY = element.offset().top;

    // Space between element and top of screen (when scrolling)
    var topMargin = 105;

    // Should probably be set in CSS; but here just for emphasis
    element.css('position', 'relative');

    $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        element.stop(false, false).animate({
            top: scrollTop < originalY
                    ? 0
                    : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
        }, 300);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This is the page: http://www.wedoblogging.com/faqs/ (U: wedoblogging P: cadb7b6c  )

As you can see, the floating div (titled: Ask Us) keeps floating down into the footer, I would like this div to stop following the scroll before it reaches the green bar above the footer.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you ever get this to stop scrolling at the footer and not just give it a scroll limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to this rule

```
top: scrollTop < originalY ? 0 : /*following code*/;
```

You add another rule that that contains the max position allowed:

```
var nextPosition = scrollTop - originalY + topMargin;
var maxPositionAllowed = 450;
top: scrollTop < originalY ? 0 : Math.min(nextPosition, maxPositionAllowed )
```

So whenever, the element tries to go bellow maxPostionAllowed, you will force it to have that distance from the top. I am not sure if 450 is the value that you want, but you can a few different to see how it looks.

So it would look something like this:

```
(function($) {
    var element = $('.follow-scroll'),
        originalY = element.offset().top;

    // Space between element and top of screen (when scrolling)
    var topMargin = 105;

    // Should probably be set in CSS; but here just for emphasis
    element.css('position', 'relative');

    $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var nextPosition = scrollTop - originalY + topMargin;
        var maxPositionAllowed = 450;

        element.stop(false, false).animate({
            top: scrollTop < originalY ? 0 : Math.min(nextPosition, maxPositionAllowed)
        }, 300);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you for your help!

I've tried adding the code (although i'm not sure I added it correctly, as the float doesn't work at all now):

This is what I have now:

Comment: `(function($) {
    var element = $('.follow-scroll'),
        originalY = element.offset().top;
    
    // Space between element and top of screen (when scrolling)
    var topMargin = 105;
    
    // Should probably be set in CSS; but here just for emphasis
    element.css('position', 'relative');
    
    $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
var nextPosition = scrollTop - originalY + topMargin;
var maxPostionAllowed = 450;`

Comment: `       element.stop(false, false).animate({
           top: scrollTop < originalY ? 0 : Math.min(nextPosition, maxPostionAllowed )
                    : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
        }, 300);
    });
})(jQuery);`

Comment: You are an error on your code. That's why it does not work at all. I edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but is there a way to modify this code so that I can set a height from the bottom of the page that the scroll wont go below? As we have tabbed content on this page, and the position from the top varies depending on which tab is open, but if we could define the maximum scroll from the footer height, then that would solve the problem.

Comment: I'm with CoolBreeze on this. This limits the amount it will scroll but not stop it from going over the footer. I essentially need this to stop scrolling at the footer.

Comment: Anyone figured out how to solve this so it stops before the footer? Or make it stop on the bottom of the containing div?